# UNIX Scripting language -need a script

Tags: unix

I have 4 files let us suppose a,b,c,d in that one is zero byte file.I want a script which will identify which is zero byte file and a script which will transfer this file into "archive" .

Thank You.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried yourself? Show the attempted code, and explain where it went wrong and where specifically you need help.

Answer (score 3):

If you had asked about Linux or the BSDs, things would have been different.  There are a whole load of scripting languages available on Linux and the BSDs, from REXX through the TENEX C Shell to Python.

But you *specifically* asked about UNIX instead.

UNIX is older than Linux and the BSDs, as well as several scripting languages, and you didn't say which version of UNIX you were asking about.  To be on the safe side, I've therefore picked a UNIX scripting language that you should be able to use even on Sixth Edition UNIX: the [Thompson Shell](http://v6shell.org/) scripting language.

Here is your script.  In the tradition of 1970s UNIX, it is powerful, taciturn, tricky in edge cases, and has no symbol longer than 7 characters.  Firmly in the Thompson Tradition, there is no unnecessary letter "e" on the end of `archiv`.  I've made one concession to the GNUistas: the addition of a `--help` option.  If you want to run the script on a BSD, where it will indeed run quite happily, you can of course eliminate such a GNUism with `head -11`.  I have, it almost goes without saying, included the bug that you specified, of only moving one zero-length file.  Enjoy.

```
#!/bin/sh6
: L
if ! { fd2 -f /dev/null goto X$1 } goto T 
: T
: <$1''
if -s $1 goto F
shift
goto L
: F
mv $1 archiv/$1
fd2 -f /dev/null goto Y
: X--help
echo Usage: $0 files...
```